# Joins and Many to Many Relationship in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, many-to-many

*So I have a database consisting of posts and categories using the following tables*

1. posts (PostID, PostName, PostCategory)
2. categories (CategoryID, CategoryName)

*then I have another table which is there to join the two together as follows*

3. posts_categories (Posts_Category_ID, PostID, CategoryID)

*I would like to know how to create an SQL Query for the following commands:*

a. Create an SQL Query to populate a single POST with MULTIPLE CATEGORIES
b. Search for all POSTS that CONTAINS MULTIPLE CATEGORIES

ex a. Create Post Named "Post1" with Categories "Digital","Analog","Linear"
ex b. Search for all Posts containing Categories "Digital" and "Linear"

**Thanks a lot for your help.**

Comment: What have you tried? How far have you gotten? It's going to take two separate INSERT statements to add rows to the `post` and `post_category` tables. (If the appropriate row in `category` doesn't already exist, you'll need a separate INSERT to add rows to that table as well.)  For the query, think in terms of either using an `EXISTS` predicate with correlated subquery for each category, or a `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT` correlated subquery, and compare the returned count value to the number of categories you're looking for. (This question has been asked and answered before, multiple times.)

Comment: I'm basically a newbie. I am able to create a new post and give it a name and manually assign a number in the PostCategory field. I wish someone to help me on how to write the queries to add multiple categories from a multiple select menu to a single post...

Comment: @Eric If you're a newbie, try starting with something simpler and building up to this -- despite all appearances, this is actually a fairly complex SQL query, and if you're just learning, it's definitely worth it to play around with the language for a while and learning it first. If you don't mind using TSQL instead of MySQL and having to create the tables in the query, take a look at [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) -- it's a great little sandbox to play around in, and you can learn all sorts of cool stuff about the SE network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about fetching the data then do a join between the tables using the chaining table. Something like below

```
select p.PostName, c.CategoryName
from posts p inner join post_categories pc on p.PostID = pc.PostID
inner join categories c on c.CategoryID = pc.CategoryID
where c.CategoryName in ('Digitl','Linear')
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help especially @Rahul ... This solved my problem partially but i'm happy with your help man... And also thanks to all those persons who disliked my post for giving me more and more motivation to move on ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I totally get your question, but the query below should return those entries in the many-to-many table that have more than one categoryId for a single postId. Let me know if this helps:

```
select *
from posts_categories pc
join (
select postId
from posts_categories
group by postId
having count(categoryId) >1
) x on x.postId = pc.postId
```

Also, you should have a unique constraint on this table for the postId and categoryId columns or make that your primary key.